# Mysql won't start - ibdata1 corrupt? - operating system error number 13 - permissions issue

Tags: mysql, file, permissions, innodb

Server shutdown from power failure.
Mysql will not start now.
Disk is not full.
Syslog is below

```
Oct 11 15:03:31 joe mysqld_safe[24757]: started
Oct 11 15:03:31 joe mysqld[24760]: 101011 15:03:31  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
Oct 11 15:03:31 joe mysqld[24760]: InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
Oct 11 15:03:31 joe mysqld[24760]: InnoDB: the directory.
Oct 11 15:03:31 joe mysqld[24760]: InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
Oct 11 15:03:31 joe mysqld[24760]: InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
Oct 11 15:03:31 joe mysqld[24760]: InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Comment: Checked permissions for ibdata1 I assume? In /var/lib/mysql on debian and its derivatives i think

Comment: Yea nothing has changed.  Permissions are owned by mysql.  The file must be corrupt.  It is the only thing I can think of at this point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The file is not corrupt.  You can find out the source of these errors with 'perror'.  i.e.

```
toaster:~ morgo$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

InnoDB has corruption detection (page checksums) and would happily tell you if that were the problem.

Either the directory permissions have changed, or your my.cnf file has been hosed, and it's trying to recreate data files somewhere else.

Comment: It's more likely an incorrect user/group than it is r/w.  From the official INSTALL-BINARY:
shell> chown -R mysql .
shell> chgrp -R mysql .
shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql # remove this step.
shell> chown -R root .
shell> chown -R mysql data

Comment: this is not a solution

Answer (score 99):

If you are using ubuntu or apparmor you should permit this change in apparmor.

Edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and change `/var/lib/mysql` with the new `DATADIR`.

It should work.

Comment: +1, I'd missed the ending / on the new directory in this file.

Comment: Thanks. The directories in apparmor conf may not be symlinks and command "service apparmor restart" was also needed.

Comment: Had the same problem as the author, but using CentOS. This answer saved me. Disabling selinux solved the issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10, saved my day. Don't have SELinux installed, but do have apparmor. Thanks!

Comment: apparmor wasted my whole day.

Comment: After editing the app armor configuration make sure to restart apparmor for it to take effect

Comment: I don't see how this answer relate to the question: what is the new DATADIR ? which change are u talking about? the answer is a about a restart - there was no change?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, saved my day, too. Thanks very much!

Comment: I've missed out the ending **slash** of the new data directory. Thanks much.

Comment: Look at `/var/log/kernl.log` to see which file access apparmor is blocking. This may not be entirely easy to figure out if, for example, you have symlinks going out of your `/var/lib/mysql` folder. 

BTW, I think the behaviour regarding symlinks changed from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

Answer (score 20):

Error:

```
101130 14:42:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
101130 18:07:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
101130 18:07:58  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Solution SeLinux SeLinux security:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mysqld restart
Deteniendo mysqld:                                         [  OK  ]
Iniciando mysqld:                                          [  FALLÓ  ]
[root@localhost ~]#  restorecon -R /var/lib/mysql/
[root@localhost ~]# service mysqld restart
Deteniendo mysqld:                                         [  OK  ]
Iniciando mysqld:                                          [  OK  ]
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: I just disabled selinux at the machine and the problem disappeared. Thanks for pointing me to right direction!

Answer (score 17):

please check this:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: on OS X installed using macports the user was _mysql and the directory was /opt/local/var/db/mysql5/, but this appears to have worked fine, many thanks.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. The error occurred to me while I was playing with /var/www folder to give client access to his app folder.

Answer (score 16):

For me, restoring the security context (selinux) did the trick

`restorecon -R /var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: I created a new partition and mounted `/var/lib/mysql` to it. It wouldn't work until I tried this. Kinda makes sense, I guess?

Answer (score 8):

### In short, (especially on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora) try

```
getenforce
```

if it replies with `Enforcing` you have SELinux up and running. Temporarily deactivate it with `setenforce 0` and see if MariaDB starts now! Rather common, especially on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora.

There's more about this further down, as well as in [this official article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/starting-and-stopping-mariadb/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/).

### In general

There are more things in a UNIX environment that might prevent file access, than just user access rights.

- Security modules like SELinux (see above) or AppArmor (as Dan mentioned) could disallow it
- Access Control Lists (ACL) could be specifically set, for the required files/directories
- Any of the parent folders could be owned by another user, and have no x (="dir access") set for others

Additionally there could be other unexpected factors, like ...

- The mysql `datadir` being set to a place, where mysql doesn't have permissions  (see `/etc/my.cnf`)
- Mysql could (strangely) be running as a different user, or the file could be simply owned by someone else

Just to mention a view things off the top of my head (feel free to edit/add to this answer btw).

### In the case, SELinux is "the problem"

For a permanent solution, you could try to restore the appropriate security context, ...

```
restorecon -R /var/lib/mysql/
```

... or just deactivate SELinux (but think about this one a little bit before doing so), by editing the config (typically in `/etc/selinux/config`) and setting `SELINUX=disabled` as suggested in following article.

- Here the **official** help page from mariadb.com: [What to do if MariaDB doesn't start](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/starting-and-stopping-mariadb/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/)
- And here something from redhat.com: [MariaDB Changing Database Location](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-MariaDB-Configuration_Examples.html#sect-Managing_Confined_Services-MariaDB-Configuration_Examples-Changing_Database_Location)

Obviously those are applicable to MySQL just the same way.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem on my CentOS box. After moving mysql data directory around I couldn't start the service anymore, even as I had copied the files with the same owner and permissions.

I had a problem with the SELinux security context. If you run your CentOS stock it has good chance to be enabled and won't let do what you want with MySQL. To fix this :

First compare the old dir and new dir using

```
ls -Z /var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
ls -Z /new/mysql/dir
```

If you see any difference it's likely to be your problem. 
To modify this :

```
chcon -R --type=mysql_db_t /new/mysql/dir
```

The -R switch is for recursion. If you only need to change one file you can omit it. 
If your context is different than mine(maybe a different distro), use the one indicated by the output of the first (it should be the 3rd field of the SELinux stuff)

```
ls -Z /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: After I ran `chcon -R --type=mysql_db_t /var/lib/mysql`, I got a bunch of `chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file 'xxxxxx'`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and fix by below steps

Working directory /var/lib/mysql

**Earlier /var/lib/mysql was owned by some unknown user**

**Changed it to mysql**

`mysql]# chown -R mysql:mysql *`

`mysql]# service mariadb start`

`Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mariadb.service`

**Works like a charm**

Answer (score 2):

When this popped up for me, I found the answer in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` configuration file. The `datadir` line did not point to the `/var/lib/mysql` directory (where the databases are). Once I put this path in, the server restarted no problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem on my CentOS box. After moving mysql data directory around I couldn't start the service anymore, even as I had copied the files with the same owner and permissions.

I had a problem with the SELinux security context. If you run your CentOS stock it has good chance to be enabled and won't let do what you want with MySQL. To fix this :

First compare the old dir and new dir using

```
ls -Z /var/lib/mysql
```

and

```
ls -Z /new/mysql/dir
```

If you see any difference it's likely to be your problem. 
To modify this :

```
chcon -R --type=mysql_db_t /new/mysql/dir
```

The -R switch is for recursion. If you only need to change one file you can omit it.

Answer (score 1):

## If you use SEL Linux

### Intall semanage

`yum whatprovides /usr/sbin/semanage` you get `policycoreutils-python-2.5-22.el7.x86_64`

### See mysqld security context

After installation `yum install policycoreutils-python` you can just look what different security context mysqld has.

```
semanage fcontext -l | grep mysqld
/etc/mysql(/.*)?                       all files    system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0
/etc/my\.cnf\.d(/.*)?                  all files    system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0
/var/log/mysql.*                       regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0
/var/lib/mysql(-files|-keyring)?(/.*)? all files    system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0
/var/run/mysqld(/.*)?                  all files    system_u:object_r:mysqld_var_run_t:s0
/var/log/mariadb(/.*)?                 all file     system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0
/var/run/mariadb(/.*)?                 all files    system_u:object_r:mysqld_var_run_t:s0
/usr/sbin/mysqld(-max)?                regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_exec_t:s0
/var/run/mysqld/mysqlmanager.*         regular file system_u:object_r:mysqlmanagerd_var_run_t:s0
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.*       regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_unit_file_t:s0
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.*      regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_unit_file_t:s0
/etc/my\.cnf                           regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0
/root/\.my\.cnf                        regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_home_t:s0
/usr/sbin/ndbd                         regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_exec_t:s0
/usr/libexec/mysqld                    regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_exec_t:s0
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe                   regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_safe_exec_t:s0
/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade                 regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_exec_t:s0
/etc/rc\.d/init\.d/mysqld              regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_initrc_exec_t:s0
/var/lib/mysql/mysql\.sock             socket       system_u:object_r:mysqld_var_run_t:s0
/usr/libexec/mysqld_safe-scl-helper    regular file system_u:object_r:mysqld_safe_exec_t:s0
/home/[^/]+/\.my\.cnf                  regular file unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_home_t:s0
```

Here you see all context for mysqld a short list with explanation

1. mysqld_etc_t - config files
2. mysqld_db_t - data db files
3. mysqld_log_t - log files
4. mysqld_exec_t - execution files

So if you have the wrong security context on your files you get a permission denied (error 13)

### Solution

```
chcon -R -u system_u -t mysqld_db_t  /var/lib/mysql
```

But check the "normal" permissions, too. I had this problem with `centos`. You have to `systemctl restart mysql` for the changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my siuation is Selinux's problem. And the
`chcon -R --type=mysql_db_t /new/mysql/dir` comes error:
`chcon: failed to change context of /new/mysql/dir to root:object_r:mysql_db_t: Invalid argument`.
So i use the command：`chcon -R root:object_r:mysqld_db_t /new/mysql/dir`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem on a Synology NAS you can fix it by following the advice of the Synology support team:

> Dear User,
>
> This has been confirmed as a known issue and we will try to fix this issue in further MariaDB release. Sorry for your inconvenience.
>
> Here is the workaround:
>
> - Please try to telnet to your DS with "root" account and password (same as admin's)
> - run the command "echo 1 > /var/services/mysql/VERSION"
> - open MariaDB package from DSM will trigger update again
> - type in the DB password and click Update will fix this issue

More info: [Synology forum](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=85982%20post)

Answer (score -10):

I had the same problem.
Did alot of research and found out this solution.
You need to run this command on ibdata1
sudo shadowprotect -u root | root

I dont know what this does.. but it worked for me.

Good luck.

Comment: You should refrain from adding solutions when you dont know what they do. You could be asking people to perform operations that cause system damage.