# Table is 'read only'

Tags: mysql, freebsd, sql-update

When I want to execute an `update` query on my table I got an error saying:

> 1036 - Table `data` is read only.

How can I fix that?

Table attributes in `/var/db/mysql` are set to `777`.

'Repair Table' function doesnt seems to help.

Is there anything I can do with that?

Comment: I had the same error in MaridDB 10.6 for table with ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
After removing this option all works as exprected

Answer (score 33, accepted):

who owns /var/db/mysql and what group are they in, should be mysql:mysql. you'll also need to restart mysql for changes to take affect

also check that the currently logged in user had GRANT access to update

Comment: Not restarting the MySQL server after changing permissions was my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

In my case, mysql config file had innodb_force_recovery = 1. Commenting that out solved the issue.

Comment: innodb_force_recovery is issue, comment this line or remove it

Comment: In /etc/my.cnf I set: innodb_file_per_table=0 and innodb_force_recovery=0. then, restart mysql service and finally it works! Thanks

Comment: But the service mariadb doesn't start without `innodb_force_recovery = 5` in my case, but I have readonly tables for `mysql_upgrade` which needs to be connected to running service. It sounds like a dead-lock.

Answer (score 11):

In case you (like me) are trying to temporarily alter data via the MySQL Workbench interface:

- If the table does not have a primary key, MySQL Workbench has no way of identifying the row you are trying to alter, so therefore you cannot alter it.
- Solution in that case is to either alter the data via another route, or simply to add a primary key to the table.

Answer (score 6):

You should change owner to MYSQL:MYSQL.

Use this command: `chown -Rf mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/DBNAME`

Answer (score 3):

My situation is everytime I needed to edit "**innodb_force_recovery = 1**" in **my.ini** to force mysql to start, and the error log showed some error said:

*Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_table_stats uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace profile/profile_commentmeta which uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\profile\profile_commentmeta.ibd*

I didn't know why this file was not able to open and it caused so many other"table read only" problems to other databases too.

So here is how I fixed this problem in a simple way without hurting other files.

1
First of all, make sure if you add **innodb_force_recovery = 1**
below **[mysqld]** in my.ini file, and it is working, under path: X:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini

2
Then next step, export all the databases through **localhost/phpmyadmin** under the **export** tab, and store them somewhere, like this:

[image: export .sql databases somewhere]

3 comment out the **data** filefolder to **data-bak**, then create a new **data** filefolder,

[image]

4 Next step, import all **.sql** database back from **phpmyadmin** panel, **please** **also copy** **phpmyadmin** filefolder from the old **data-bak** filefolder to the new **data** filefolder. If any file is necessary, go back to data-bak filefolder to copy and paste.

[image]

Now all fixed and done, don't need to force mysql to start everytime.
Hope this also works for you.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have write access to the database file. Check the permissions and the owner of the file.

Comment: if you change the permissions manually don't forget to issue a FLUSH PRIVILEGES command.

Answer (score 0):

On windows I use Xampp server I comment the line in **my.ini**
`innodb_force_recovery = 1`  to `#innodb_force_recovery = 1` the problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by editing app. armour configuration file. Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563327/3175566[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563327/3175566)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you get read only error from your table storage engine.
Check you Storage Engine, maybe if it is MRG_MYISAM change it to MyISAM and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running selinux in enforcing mode then check your /var/log/messages for audit faults. If you see the tell-tale "****" messages about selinux blocking write access to your table files in / then you need to relabel those files so that they have this label:

*system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0*

What you could have is a broken label from copying those files over from a user directory (such as during a recovery attempt).

There's a great resource for selinux here:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html

Just remember that you will need to do this for all of those files, which could be many. Then you will want to run the "restorecon -R -v " command to get the recursive (-R) application of the new labels. There is no support for -R in the semanage command, as far as I could tell.

For reference, the semanage command to relabel looks like this:

semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t 'filename'

The quoting of the file name is critical for the command to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a table with read-only state set and when I tried to restart mysql service it would not even start again and with no descriptive error.

Solution was to run `fsck` on the drive (with many fixes), which was advised after Ubuntu reboot.

I'm running Ubuntu in VirtualBox under Windows and it often hangs or is having functionality problems.

Answer (score -1):

One other way to receive this error is to create your table with a "Like" statement and use as source a merged table. That way the newly create table is read-only and can't "receive" any new records.

so

```
CREATE TABLE ic.icdrs_kw37 LIKE ic.icdrs ... #<- a merged table.
```

then:

```
REPLACE INTO ic.icdrs_kw37 ...  # -> "Table is read-only"
```

bug or feature?