# ERROR 1036 (HY000): Table 'Atable_name' is read only

Tags: mysql

I got this error `ERROR 1036 (HY000): Table 'AvailCounterDaily' is read only` when i trying to run sql file from my desktop. like

```
 mysql> source Desktop/file_name.sql
```

please, tell me how to solved? I change permmision of file/folder to 777 or 755 (try both).

Comment: What queries are being executed? i.e. what's inside Desktop/file_name.sql ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table is 'read only'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575914/table-is-read-only)

Comment: @EWit insert query is there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have no GRANT to change data or table structure on this table 'AvailCounterDaily'. Please check or ask your admin.