# MySQL Read Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

So I experienced an error with my magento eccommerce site that I havent seen before.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1015 Can't lock file (errno: 165 "Table is read only")
```

tried to restart table, got this error  https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/227018/yPU5fpVpENUPx38Ls0wDcPhvxhPXEGcl/

What can be a solution to fix this.

Comment: check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575914/table-is-read-only

Comment: i should add using Cpanel and shell or anything else.

Comment: Check the permissions of the dbuser you are using

Comment: it is all checked off as all access.

Comment: have you checked group??