# #1036 - Table is read only in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, host

I'm using a database host with phpMyAdmin. This host isn't mine.

I executed this code in the phpMyAdmin of this host:

```
INSERT INTO `fronton`(`id`, `Name`, `number`, `cover`, `ligth`, `type`, `height`, `widht`, `lenght`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `status`, `time`, `price`) VALUES (NULL , 'Barrikako Frontoia', '9', '1', '2', '0', NULL , NULL , NULL , '0,3454232', '0,32243243', '0', '0', '0')
```

And this error appear:

> ## 1036 - Table 'fronton' is read only

I have been searching a lot about it, but i haven't found anything. Does anyone know what i can do about this?

Updated:

Now i am using a host service called [Hostinger](http://www.hostinger.es/) and i have the same problem.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @vkp (insert is dml)

Comment: duplicate of [table-is-read-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575914/table-is-read-only)

Comment: This question is not duplicate, because this link speaks about a server of MySQL and about the path /var/db/mysql and his privileges. But in my case, i can't access to that folder or apply some privilege with GRANT. What i can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution to the problem. Instead of use this code:

```
ENGINE=MRG_MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

i have to use:

```
ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

it was a engine error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using windows server than you comment line `innodb_force_recovery = 1` to `#innodb_force_recovery = 1` in my.ini

It works for me.

Comment: I forgot that I added this line. :D Thank you.