# Mysql error 1036 Table is read only

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-10

I'm using xampp to run mysql, and I've created a database for a lost and found website.

The database is really simple, only two tables are used:
students
&
lost_items

I am trying to insert data into the students table, but it keeps saying that this table is read only. I've read some solutions and they said I need to use sudo and set the group privileges, but where do I put in these commands?

Comment: Where do I enter this command?

Comment: Are you running Windows or Unix?

Comment: running windows 10

Comment: What you have read is not match to your needs because you are running Windows and `sudo` is a command for Unix and Unix-like operating system.

Comment: so how do I solve this problem if im using windows

Comment: What engine are you using? Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE STUDENTS` and update your question.

Comment: There can be multiple reason for this issue 1) Check the user you are using have all required permission granted 2) Try checking with database engine it might creating an issue. few ref. article for existing issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161224/1036-table-is-read-only-in-phpmyadmin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575914/table-is-read-only , hope any of this can give you some idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem in ubuntu and xampp.

1. In file config,  after block innodb set --> innodb_force_recovery = 1
2. sudo chmod 777 -R  /opt/lampp/var/mysql
3. Сomment out line #innodb_force_recovery = 1
4. restart MySQL

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Get your data directories by following commands.

```
sudo cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep -i datadir
```

or 
    sudo cat /etc/my.cnf | grep -i datadir

```
sudo chown -cR mysql:mysql /Path/mysql/datadir/
```

And restart mysql process

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sudo is a linux command no? i am using windows 10 and it doesnt recognize sudo