# Could not be able to enter data in database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

```
   <html>

   <head>
   <title>Add New Record in MySQL Database</title>
   </head>

    <body>
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'password';
        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

        if(! $conn ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
           $emp_name = addslashes ($_POST['emp_name']);
           $emp_address = addslashes ($_POST['emp_address']);
        }else {
           $emp_name = $_POST['emp_name'];
           $emp_address = $_POST['emp_address'];
        }

        $emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];

        $sql = "insert into employee(emp_name,emp_address, emp_salary)values('$emp_name','$emp_address','$emp_salary')";

        mysqli_select_db($conn,"test_db");
        $retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        if(!$retval) {
           die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Entered data successfully\n";

        mysql_close($conn);
     }else {
        ?>

           <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
              <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1" 
                 cellpadding = "2">

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Employee Name</td>
                    <td><input name = "emp_name" type = "text" 
                       id = "emp_name"></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Employee Address</td>
                    <td><input name = "emp_address" type = "text" 
                       id = "emp_address"></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100">Employee Salary</td>
                    <td><input name = "emp_salary" type = "text" 
                       id = "emp_salary"></td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100"> </td>
                    <td> </td>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                    <td width = "100"> </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name = "add" type = "submit" id = "add" 
                          value = "Add Employee">
                    </td>
                 </tr>

              </table>
           </form>

        <?php
     }
  ?>
```

> when I am trying to enter the value and pressing the submit button at this time I am not getting any error but I cannot be able to enter the value in database.
>   The problem is I am getting text as "Could not enter data: Table 'employee' is read only".Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem ?
>
> I have created the database (test_db) and table (employee ) in wamp server.

Comment: `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>` ???? did u defined it anywhere? if yes than u forgot to add echo here

Comment: I am trying to add values from form.

Comment: Have you tried to echo the query, like `echo $sql;`?

Comment: Please change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error($conn)` and then update your answer with the error message.

Comment: use `action = ""` instead of `action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>"`

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli. Stop it. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of prepared statements and bind_param, otherwise you're open for SQL injection and possible quoting issues.

Comment: I am getting Could not enter data: Table 'employee' is read only as output @RossWilson

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575914/table-is-read-only

Comment: Thanks sir @RossWilson. My problem got solved now .The mistake  was i I used  MRG_MYISAM as storage instead of  myisam as storage .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is solved. Even though, I will strongly recommend you to use Prepared Statements, otherwise your code is open for SQL injection and possible quoting issues.

> You're mixing mysql and mysqli. Stop it. Since you're using mysqli,
>   take advantage of prepared statements and bind_param, otherwise you're
>   open for SQL injection and possible quoting issues. – @**aynber**

***Changes***

- Change `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());` To `die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());`
- Change `mysql_close($conn);` To `mysqli_close($conn);`
- Change `action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>"` To `action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`
- Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

***Updated Code***

```
<html>

   <head>
    <title>Add New Record in MySQL Database</title>
   </head>

    <body>
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'password';
        $db = "test_db";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

        if(! $conn ) {
           die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO employee(emp_name,emp_address, emp_salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $_POST['emp_name'], $_POST['emp_address'], $_POST['emp_salary']);

        if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
           die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        echo "Entered data successfully\n";

        mysqli_close($conn);
     } else {
        ?>
           <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <table width = "400" border = "0" cellspacing = "1"  cellpadding = "2">
                    <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Employee Name</td>
                        <td><input name = "emp_name" type = "text" id = "emp_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Employee Address</td>
                        <td><input name = "emp_address" type = "text" id = "emp_address"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Employee Salary</td>
                        <td><input name = "emp_salary" type = "text" id = "emp_salary"></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td><input name = "add" type = "submit" id = "add" value = "Add Employee"></td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
           </form>

        <?php
     }
  ?>
```

***Quick Look***

- [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [PHP_SELF](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html)
- [Table is 'read only' : [Solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575914/table-is-read-only)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you user is not granted to enter data into you table
Please edit schema_name, and execute query on you DB:

GRANT ALL ON TABLE schema_name.employee TO root;

Also you can try without schema:
GRANT ALL ON TABLE employee TO root;