# Table 'X' is read only, using a Mac, how can I fix this?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I used an insert statement

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO patient_free_new (fname, lname, email, age, pwd, cpwd) 
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$age', '$password', '$cpassword')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

and I get the following every time I press the submit button on my form: Table 'patient_free_new' is read only

Any idea how to fix this? I'm using a Mac with XAMPP

Comment: might want to refer this link http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/adding-a-new-user-to-a-mysql-database-in-xampp

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575914/table-is-read-only

Comment: I already checked both of those links but I still have no luck

Comment: are you logged in as the root user?

Comment: @DhavalChheda no I made a new user with my name, and granted all the privileges

Comment: so login with the root user and see if it works ?

Comment: @DhavalChheda Just tried it, it still says its read only

Answer (score 1):

I use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) and when I stumble upon this problem once I forgot to give rights to my user to this database.