# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'user' is read only

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a register (sign up) page but when I want to execute the insert command this error message appears:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'user' is read only in C:\xampp\htdocs\pfa\login.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pfa\login.php(12): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO use...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pfa\login.php on line 12

This is the PHP code:

I changed the privilege of all users (including "root" and gave them ALL PRIVILEGES
but still the same problem:
table user is on read only

Comment: Check if anything mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/q/9575914/1427878 helps.