# InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation not fixed after changing permissions in /var/lib/mysql/ or disabling selinux

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

When I run `mysql`, I get the error of `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. `mysqld` gives the error of

```
    150101 12:08:19 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/lamp-update.lower-test
    150101 12:08:19 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/lamp-update.lower-test
    150101 12:08:19 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

    150101 12:08:19 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
    150101 12:08:19 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
    150101 12:08:19 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
    150101 12:08:19 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    150101 12:08:19 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    150101 12:08:19 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    150101 12:08:19 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    150101 12:08:19 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    150101 12:08:19 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    150101 12:08:19  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
    InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
    InnoDB: the directory.
    InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
    InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
    InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

`sudo mysqld` gives the output of `150101 12:11:59 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.`

I am running a virtual ubuntu linux server. Mysql has worked without a problem until yesterday, when I got this error.

I have tried to set the permissions of the files in /var/lib/mysql to 660, /var/lib/mysql to 755, and its subdirectories to 700. I then ran `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`. Then, I tried rebooting my server, and running mysqld. I got the same error.

Then, I tried disabling selinux by running `sudo vim /etc/selinux/semanage.conf` and adding `SELINUX=disabled` to the file as the first line. I rebooted again, and got the same error.

This is the extent of any advice I have seen on stackexchange or other sites.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I could do?

Thank you,

Daniel

## Edit:

I "solved" my problem by running mysqld as root, but this doesn't seem like a good idea security wise, so I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: check out these links, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: did you check apparmor?

Comment: please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907666/mysql-wont-start-ibdata1-corrupt-operating-system-error-number-13-permis

Comment: output of `sestatus`?

Answer (score 7):

I could solve this by changing the ownership of the folder to mysql from group root (sudo chown -R mysql:root folder). Once I did this, all started to work again.

Regards

Comment: This works, but has the same security risks as a MySQL-Root user. Which means, if the DB has a vulnerability, the tester has your server.

Comment: Why should that be risky if mysql is the owner of the data-folder?
For me the solution was the same - somehow mysql user lost writing permission to the data folder (but in my case it was a docker environment)

Answer (score 4):

In my case SELinux was enabled and by disabling SELinux i was able to start the service

To disable SELlinux, edit

> /etc/sysconfig/selinux

and set

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Reboot and verify with command

```
sestatus
```

Folder permissions in my case are

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/efs/fs1/mysql

chmod -R 750 /mnt/efs/fs1/mysql
```

where /mnt/efs/fs1/mysql is my data directory

Comment: Yeah, I was migrating entire backed-up database-folder structure from another server and couldn't get mySQL to start despite ensuring that everything was owned my the correct mysql user and that the standard file-permissions were set correctly). Finally realized it as the SELinux extra layer of security. I then did a full sql dump, renabled SELinux, and then installed "correctly" from the dump file

Answer (score 0):

I also troubled with this problem.I used 'setenforce 0' this command and then mysql service successfully start.Maybe you can try it.Good luck

Answer (score -5):

first, type these command below;

- chown -R root:mysql /opt/lampp/var/mysql
- chown -R root:mysql /opt/lampp/mysql
- chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/var/mysql
- chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/mysql

second, rerun the installer.

it worked for me.