# How to fix mysql database

Tags: debian, mysql

It all started when my server was not shut down properly. On the next boot mysql failed to start so I tried to start it with `service mysql restart` but that failed and said `Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`

http://hastebin.com/uyijoquyol.coffee
http://hastebin.com/fekepowuzi.avrasm

I have a feeling the database is corrupt. Is there a way to repair the files to working order?

Comment: Can you post the output of `systemctl status mysql.service`?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/fekepowuzi.avrasm

Comment: And in the log file of mysql (/var/log/)?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/vedulicogo.vhdl

Comment: Which server are you using?
Regards.

Comment: debian 8 with mysql 5.5

Comment: After changing the perms this error showed up.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aJ5KkJJf

Comment: I'm sorry but i never have a corruption and so i can't help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107406/discussion-between-averythomas-and-conve).

Comment: Try starting the service by this command:/etc/init.d/
mysqld start or service mysql start

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a permission issue, to start with:

```
160325 18:39:20  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Have a look here:

[Mysql won't start - ibdata1 corrupt? - operating system error number 13 - permissions issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907666/mysql-wont-start-ibdata1-corrupt-operating-system-error-number-13-permis)

Regards