# MySQL running in safe mode but not in normal mode. Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)

Tags: mysql

My server accidentally got hard rebooted yesterday and after that the MySQL service isn't starting.

On running `sudo service mysql status`

the response was stuck at `mysql stop/waiting`

On running `mysqld --verbose` this is the response I got

```js
200305 12:47:59 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

200305 12:47:59 [Warning] The syntax '--log-slow-queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--slow-query-log'/'--slow-query-log-file' instead.

200305 12:47:59 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log) starting as process 2536 ...

200305 12:47:59 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/ip-172-31-12-215.lower-test

200305 12:47:59 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/ip-172-31-12-215.lower-test

200305 12:47:59 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root



200305 12:47:59 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

200305 12:47:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)

200305 12:47:59 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

200305 12:47:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

200305 12:47:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

200305 12:47:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8

200305 12:47:59 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

200305 12:47:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G

200305 12:47:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

200305 12:47:59  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.

InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to

InnoDB: the directory.

InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1

InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.

InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Currently I can run mysql in safe mode but I'm not sure if there are any issue's in doing that and since this is in production I can't play around with different solutions which would lead to a longer downtime.

TIA

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907666/mysql-wont-start-ibdata1-corrupt-operating-system-error-number-13-permis

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, this is about administering a mysql instance. While this question is off topic here on SO, you can get more help at the dba sister site of SO.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have upgraded your MySQL server and forgot to run [mysql_upgrade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/) 
and this is what the error says in your error log.

> 200305 12:47:59 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run
>   mysql_upgrade to create it.

in your terminal just run with `sudo` if needed :

```
mysql_upgrade
```